# Zsh bad substitution error when installing Influxdb2.0

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, influxdb, influxdb-2

I am following the installation instructions from this [article](https://citizix.com/how-to-install-and-configure-influxdb2-in-debian-11/) but I get a `bad substitution error` from `zsh` when executing this command:

```
export DISTRIB_ID=$(lsb_release -si); export DISTRIB_CODENAME=$(lsb_release -sc)
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/${DISTRIB_ID,,} ${DISTRIB_CODENAME} stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdb.list > /dev/null
```

What am I supposed to change for zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${DISTRIB_ID,,}` is a Bash-specific parameter expansion to lowercase the value of the variable.

https://askubuntu.com/a/383360/25077 suggests `${(L)DISTRIB_ID}` as a corresponding operation in Zsh.

But there is no real reason for this to use any constructs specific to either shell; the operation is simple to do portably in POSIX `sh` too (albeit at the cost of an external process).

For what it's worth, unless there are other reasons you need to, the `export` statements here are unnecessary, too. See also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

```
distrib_id=$(lsb_release -si | tr A-Z a-z)
distrib_codename=$(lsb_release -sc)
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/$distrib_id $distrib_codename stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdb.list > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment in the original post says the `${DISTRIB_ID,,}` is used in bash to expand the parameter in lower case. The same in zsh is done by `${DISTRIB_ID:l}`.

So the whole working command in zsh is:

```
export DISTRIB_ID=$(lsb_release -si); export DISTRIB_CODENAME=$(lsb_release -sc)
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdb.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/${DISTRIB_ID:l} ${DISTRIB_CODENAME} stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdb.list > /dev/null
```